# What is the use of logical pixel in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, pixel

I am not interested in inside workings of logical pixels, I just want to know if flutter automatically use logical pixel

```
Container(
  width:100,
  child:...
)
```

Does flutter uses 100 pixel or logical pixel as width here, I can't figure it out.

Comment: yes, it uses logical pixels

Comment: @pskink Like, all the time, without specifying ?

Comment: specifying what? if you write `width: 100` it is always 100 logical pixels

Comment: @pskink Thanks, if you will post it as answer, I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print screen width

```
double kScreenWidth(BuildContext ctx) => MediaQuery.of(ctx).size.width;
```

you can see what it is like

```
Container(width: 100, ...)
```

logical pixels

So obvious,

What you see is what you got.

---

> Flutter follows a simple density-based format like iOS. Assets might be 1.0x, 2.0x, 3.0x, or any other multiplier.

> **Flutter doesn’t have dps but there are logical pixels, which are basically the same as device-independent pixels.** The so-called devicePixelRatio expresses the ratio of physical pixels in a single logical pixel.

from [flutter dev doc](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs)

Comment: This doesn't answer my doubt, it just says what logical pixel is.